# what's the fastest object comparison in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I need to create a set of objects (the types and values don't matter, as long as they are distinct) that have very fast comparisons.  I'm currently using NSString for comparison, but I imagine there must be something faster.  NSNumber maybe?  Perhaps I could do an primitive comparison using its int value?

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you can't compare addresses?

Comment: yes, of course.  Should have thought of it myself.  I'm still curious, though, even though this is the answer I'll use.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest object comparison method is NSObject's, which just compares pointer equality (`self == argument`).

If you want to create a bunch of objects that are only important for their identity, creating plain NSObjects is a decent way to go about it. You can manually compare them using pointer equality for maximum speed, and if some other class wants to use `isEqual:`, it's still as efficient as it can be.

Kind of an ineffective optimization in most cases, though.